# how to get value of selected row in DropDown and Grid view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, gridview, dropdown

i have 2 question...
1. i have a gridview that bind some data form database that way

```
DataSource = Company.GetAllCompany();
        dgvCompanys.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvCompanys.DataSource = _DataSource;

        dgvcolNameEn.DataPropertyName = "MyEnglishName";
        dgvcolAddress.DataPropertyName = "MyAddress";
        dgvcolCode.DataPropertyName = "MyCode";
        dgvcolKeyId.DataPropertyName = "MyKeyId";
```

it's worked now i want get the KeyId of selected row

```
private void dgvCompanys_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (dgvCompanys.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
        mtxtCode.Text=dgvCompanys.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

this code have this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
what i have to do for this?
question 2.i have textboxdropdownlist(devComponent)
and sourced that way:

```
List<Company> _DataCompany;
_DataCompany = Company.GetAllCompany();
        cmbCompany.DisplayMember = "MyEnglishName";
        cmbCompany.DataSource = _DataCompany;
```

that worked correctly but i want get KeyId of rows selected in dropdown now what i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 : perhaps your dataset have only one column, so the right code is :

```
dgvCompanys.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Question 2 is not clear for me, but you can access to the selected item with :

```
DropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Comment: q1.still it have Error->Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
q2.i will show the field name but want get Id Field

Comment: q1. if Cell.value[0] is null, the ToString() operation raise an exception, perhaps ^^ q2. do you test SelectedValue or SelectedText properties ?